# android is there build in listview contains imageview and textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml

I am using listview `simple_list_item_1` which is build in and its code is:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

I use it like this:

```
String functions[] = new String[] { "asdf", "asdfasdf",
            "asdf", "asdfasdfasdf" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, functions));
    }
```

It works good, but I am asking if android has a build in listview that each row of it contains an imageview and a textview,
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no layout with an ImageView and TextView in the SDK.
However you can easily create one.  You need extend ArrayAdapter and override `getView()`. Here is a basic [tutorial](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) to help you.

You can also use one of the [`android:drawable___`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableBottom) attributes which combines the two Views.

Comment: thanks for your answer , +1 to you, I know how to do it manually but i am just asking if there is a build it thing because it is a very common listview so I have thought that google should build such a list, thanks

Comment: the tutorial link redirects to a 404